# Combine many MySQL queries with logic into data file

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, query-optimization

Background:

I am parsing a 330 meg xml file into a DB (netflix catalog) using PHP script from the console.

I can successfully add about 1,500 titles every 3 seconds **until** i addd the logic to add actors, genre and formats. These are separate tables linked by an associative table.

**right now I have to run many, many queries for each title**, in this order ( i truncate all tables first, to eliminate old titles, genres, etc)

1. add new title to 'titles' and capture insert id
2. check actor table for exising actor
3. if present, get id, if not insert
   actor and get insert id
4. insert title id and actor id into
   associative table

(steps 2-4 are repeated for genres too)

This drops my speed don to about 10 per 3 seconds. which would take eternitty to add the ~250,00 titles.

**so how would I combine the 4 queries into a single query, without adding duplicate actors or genres**

My goal is to just write all queries into a data file, and do a bulk insert.

I started by writing all associative queries into a data file, but it didn't do much for performance.

---

I start by inserting th etitle, and saving ID

```
function insertTitle($nfid, $title, $year){
    $query="INSERT INTO ".$this->titles_table." (nf_id, title, year ) VALUES ('$nfid','$title','$year')";
    mysql_query($query);
    $this->updatedTitleCount++;
    return mysql_insert_id();
}
```

that is then used in conjunction with each actor's name to create the association

```
function linkActor($value, $title_id){
    //check if we already know value
    $query="SELECT * FROM ".$this->persons_table." WHERE person = '$value' LIMIT 0,1";
    //echo "<br>".$query."<br>";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $value_id=$row['id'];
        }
    }else{
        //no value known, add to persons table
        $query="INSERT INTO ".$this->persons_table." (person) VALUES ('$value')";
        mysql_query($query);
        $value_id=mysql_insert_id();

    }   
    //echo "linking title:".$title_id." with rel:".$value_id;
    $query = " INSERT INTO ".$this->title_persons_table." (title_id,person_id) VALUE ('$title_id','$value_id');";
    //mysql_query($query);
    //write query to data file to be read in bulk style
    fwrite($this->fh, $query);
}
```

Comment: I cannot give you the exact query for your task, but have a look at [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: This should be an incredibly fast operation - your entire db will fit in ram - you can do the whole thing in memory and insert it afterwards if you like, 250k rows is nothing.

Comment: I think that would be ideal if I knew all actors existed, and just needed to insert into the associative table. But if the actor did not exist, the select insert would not remedy that.

Comment: 250,000 rows is just the titles table.
after only 64 titles, i have about 10,000 records in the associaitve table.

I tried AUTOCOMMIT=0, and START TRANSACTION, COMMIT for every 1000 records, and didnt see much change.

I am diggin into my code to make sure everything is kosher with the aomount of data that is neded for the ass. tables... seeems way excessive.

Comment: haha - yeah 10,00 was def. bogus. I noticed the actor and formats ass. count much lower then genre..
$this->genreArray==array(); // there your probvlem,!

i was not reseting my genre array after each title update.

So now i am insertin about ~50 tiles/second (including genres, formnats, actors and 3 ass. tables) but I still think i can do better.  

I really appreciate everyone's help and will try to incorporate what I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect opportunity for using [prepared statements](http://docs.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).
Also take a look at the tips at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html, e.g.

> To speed up INSERT operations that are performed with multiple statements for nontransactional tables, lock your tables

You can also decrease the number of queries. E.g. you can eliminate the `SELECT...FROM persons_table` to obtain the id by using `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` and [LAST_INSERT_ID(**expr**)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

( sorry, running out of time for a lengthy description, but I wrote an example before noticing the time ;-) If this answer isn't downvoted too much I can hand it in later. )

```
class Foo {
  protected $persons_table='personsTemp';
  protected $pdo;
  protected $stmts = array();

  public function __construct($pdo) {
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
    $this->stmts['InsertPersons'] = $pdo->prepare('
      INSERT INTO
        '.$this->persons_table.'
        (person)
      VALUES
        (:person)
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
    ');
  }

  public function getActorId($name) {
    $this->stmts['InsertPersons']->execute(array(':person'=>$name));
    return $this->pdo->lastInsertId('id');
  }
}

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", 'localonly', 'localonly'); 
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// create a temporary/test table
$pdo->exec('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE personsTemp (id int auto_increment, person varchar(32), primary key(id), unique key idxPerson(person))');
// and fill in some data
foreach(range('A', 'D') as $p) {
  $pdo->exec("INSERT INTO personsTemp (person) VALUES ('Person $p')");
}

$foo = new Foo($pdo);
foreach( array('Person A', 'Person C', 'Person Z', 'Person B', 'Person Y', 'Person A', 'Person Z', 'Person A') as $name) {
  echo $name, ' -> ', $foo->getActorId($name), "\n";
}
```

prints

```
Person A -> 1
Person C -> 3
Person Z -> 5
Person B -> 2
Person Y -> 6
Person A -> 1
Person Z -> 5
Person A -> 1
```

(someone might want to start a discussion whether a getXYZ() function should perform an INSERT or not  ...but not me, not now....)

Comment: This  looks promising for the reference tables and should save me thousands of query by the end of the job.
Thanks!

Comment: Nice I have boosted my count to 100 titles per second by leverageing this for genres, formats and actors.

DO you know that tthe performance of the insert into v a select is?

Answer (score 1):

Your performance is glacially slow; something is very Wrong. I assume the following

- You run your dedicated, otherwise-idle database server on respectable hardware
- You have tuned it to some extent (i.e. at least configure it to use a few gigs of ram properly) - engine-specific optimisations will be required

You may be being stung by doing lots of tiny operations with autocommit on; this is a mistake as it generates an unreasonable number of disc IO operations. You should do a large amount of work (100, 1000 records etc) in a single transaction then commit it.

The lookups may be slowing things down because of the simple overhead of doing the queries (the queries themselves will be really easy as you'll have an index on actor name).

I also question your method of assuming that no two actors have the same name - surely your original database contains a unique actor ID, so you don't get them mixed up?

Comment: Thanks Mark

I am running a dedicated virtualized server for the db, and the hardware is decent, but my memory usage is capped around 1gig. Even so , looking at my performance stats, memory use is flat, so I think I need to optimize the server to be a little more agressive. I guess i have some reading to do.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a language other than PHP? If not, are you running this as a PHP stand-alone script or through a webserver? The webserver is probably adding a lot of overhead you don't need.

I do something very similar at work, using Python, and can insert a couple thousand rows (with associative table lookups) per second on your standard 3.4 GHz, 3GB RAM, machine. MySQL database isn't hosted locally but within the LAN.

Comment: Thanks Michael , I added the details above. Unfortunately I am not very proficient with python. And I am running the script from the command line to avoid apache's overhead.